# how to validate or check textcontent contains phone, email id or url

Tags: javascript, php

```
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script> function validate()  
        {  
        var message = document.form1.Message.value;

         var emailPat = /^(\".*\"|[A-Za-z]\w*)@(\[\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3}){3}]|[A-Za-z]\w*(\.[A-Za-z]\w*)+)$/
         var RE = /^[\d\.\-]+$/;
         var Url = "^[A-Za-z]+://[A-Za-z0-9-_]+\\.[A-Za-z0-9-_%&\?\/.=]+$";
    if (message.match(emailPat)) {
        alert("Your Message contains an email! please remove ..");
        return false;
    } 
    else if(RE.test(message))
        {
            alert("Your Message contains an phone number! please remove ..");
            return false;
        }

    else if (message.match(Url)) {
       alert("Contains a URL.");
       return false;
    }   


       return true;
    }
        </script>
    </head>
     <body>
    <form name="form1" onsubmit=" return validate();">

    Your Message:<br><textarea name="Message" cols="60" rows="3" wrap="OFF"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
     </form>
    </body>
```

here i tried to put one textarea with out any phone, email id or url, here i faild to connect all if i given single like only email id its working , when i tried to give multiple it fails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex expressions contain **special symbols** `^` and `$`, which correspond to **the beginning and the end of the line**.

It means that your regex

```
/^(\".*\"|[A-Za-z]\w*)@(\[\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3}){3}]|[A-Za-z]\w*(\.[A-Za-z]\w*)+)$/
```

checks that after the line begins (`^`) there should be some email `(\".*\"|[A-Za-z]\w*)@(\[\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3}){3}]|[A-Za-z]\w*(\.[A-Za-z]\w*)+)` and then the line ends (`$`). So if you test the string which has some text preceeding or following the email, the match won't work.

When you want to check the string for containing some substrings matching regex, you should not include `^` and `$` symbols.

So try:

```
var emailPat = /(\".*\"|[A-Za-z]\w*)@(\[\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3}){3}]|[A-Za-z]\w*(\.[A-Za-z]\w*)+)/
var RE = /[\d\.\-]+/;
var Url = "[A-Za-z]+://[A-Za-z0-9-_]+\\.[A-Za-z0-9-_%&\?\/.=]+";
```

Comment: how to do this same functionality in php